# How to convert string to raw hexadecimal?

Tags: python, string, discord, hex, discord.py

I have a discord bot, which allows to add a default color to config.

```
{
   "Embed-Default-Color": "0x000000"
}
```

It doesn't allow raw input without "" and causes problems with usage:

```
with open("config.json") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

DEFAULT_COLOR = config.get("Embed-Default-Color")

em = discord.Embed(title="Hi", description="I'm Gabe Newell", color=DEFAULT_COLOR)
```

(Code used only for context showcase, there are no errors like config not found, etc.)

Error returns `TypeError: Cannot use string for argument discord.Colour => "0x000000"`

How can I convert the string to hexadecimal, without letting it convert anything as it already is hexadecimal, but only in wrong format?

Comment: Are you asking how to covert and string containing a hexdecimal to an integer? Why doesn't int("0x000000",16) not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
hexastr = "hexa value"
hexa = int("0x" + hexastr, 16)
```

Comment: That's the solution, works flawless, though I don't know why it had to be this way hehe

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing it as a string, pass it as a discord color object.

```
em = discord.Embed(title="Hi", description="I'm Gabe Newell", color=discord.Colour(int(DEFAULT_COLOR,16)))
```

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Expected int parameter, received str instead.

It throws the same error in that case

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra convert option from python for hexadecimal numbers `hex()`, so you can probably use that:

```
with open("config.json") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

DEFAULT_COLOR = config.get("Embed-Default-Color")

em = discord.Embed(title="Hi", description="I'm Gabe Newell", color=hex(DEFAULT_COLOR))
```

Comment: That's what I had tried, but it tries to convert to int first and throws an error because there is an "x" in there, which is desperately needed. hex also converts the integer to 16-numeric system, even though the number provided is already a hex number, which only needs declaration

Comment: So maybe you can just save the hexdec as hexdec? So without any strings yk